# How we can get i-Frame using AVAssetDownloadTask when downloading video objective c

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, avassetdownloadtask

I am working on iOS app with Objective C where we are downloaded a Video. When i am playing this video in offline video is playing fine but Fast-forward and rewind are not working for downloaded content in Offline playback mode.Please suggest what can i do.